# What characters on Heroes have the ability to manipulate space and time?

Tags: powers, heroes

In the show *Heroes*, there are a bunch of people who can do crazy things to space and time, including stopping it.

With the large cast, it's hard to keep track of who can do what, but who has the ability to stop time? What are its limitations? Do the space-time manipulators relate to each other in any way?

Comment: Hi Kiana, there are [new guidelines](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/are-some-questions-too-simple/#comments) that try to get questions away from being easily answered by a quick Google search: I've edited your question to keep the spirit of your question intact but try to expand and get more information.

Comment: Kiana, was this answer enough for you?

Answer (score 15):

The main character who can stop time is [Hiro Nakamura](http://heroeswiki.com/Hiro), but he doesn't technically "stop time": he can merely slow it down a great deal. In the episode ["The Second Coming"](http://heroeswiki.com/Episode%3aThe_Second_Coming), he runs into [Daphne](http://heroeswiki.com/Daphne) who has super speed and can move normally to Hiro's frame of reference.

Additionally, by virtue of their unique power-stealing/replicating abilities, both [Peter](http://heroeswiki.com/Peter_Petrelli) and [Arthur Petrelli](http://heroeswiki.com/Arthur) had the same power Hiro has, at least temporarily. Peter gets it by being in close proximity to Hiro, and Arthur gets it by stealing all of Peter's abilities.

Comment: Y'know, I wonder if Sylar ever had time manipulation abilities.  For a while he was able to absorb powers the same way as Peter originally could, and he was near Peter and Arthur fairly often..

Comment: Sylar always had to mess with a subject's brain to steal their abilities, his wasn't proximity based like Peter's. This killed all of his victims, except for Claire, I believe.

Comment: @Zoneman, Sylar didn't actually need to kill, he admits in the fourth season that he just likes doing that. He steals abilities by understanding how they work, which is his original ability. That's why he always makes them show him what they do first.

Answer (score 2):

In season 4 there' an additional character who can manipulate time [Arnold](http://heroeswiki.com/Arnold), who's a part of the [Sullivan Bros. Carnival](http://heroeswiki.com/Sullivan_Bros._Carnival):

- He sends Samuel back into the past several times (once to meet young Hiro, young Ando and young Kimiko at the carnival)
- Traps Charlie in the past so Samuel can coerce Hiro into doing his bidding.